# selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string using waits and expected conditions

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I am using Python 3.7 and Selenium 3.141.0. On slow-loading pages, it often helps to use code like this to capture DOM objects:

```
myDiv = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.myClass")))
```

That code searches an entire page for a `<div>` element that has class `myClass`. But I sometimes want to use `presence_of_element_located()` to search only within a given WebElement object. For example, building on the code above, I want to run code like this:

```
myDiv2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    myDiv.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.myClass2")))
```

That second code block doesn't work; I get an error message telling me, understandably, that `presence_of_element_located()` isn't a method of WebElement objects. The code also fails if I replace `myDiv.presence_of_element_located()` with `myDiv.find_element()`. In that case, I get an invalid-argument message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string
```

Is there a way to use waits and expected conditions to test the presence of elements, or otherwise search for elements, while restricting the search to a WebElement object like `myDiv`? In a sense, this can be done by writing a complex CSS or Xpath selector—but I would like to avoid that.

I've checked SO posts and the [Selenium documentation of expected conditions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html?highlight=expected), but I haven't found anything that speaks to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *presence_of_element_located()*

[`presence_of_element_located()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located) is an expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible and is used to find the element returns the WebElement once it is located.

Once the element `myDiv` is returned through:

```
myDiv = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.myClass")))
```

To search another element with respect to the found WebElement you can use the following solution:

```
myDiv2 = WebDriverWait(myDiv, 60).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.myClass2")))
```

Answer (score 1):

[Under the hood](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py#L54), `presence_of_element_located` only uses `find_element` and returns the element found.

Having this in mind, you can create your own custom expected conditions method `presence_of_element_located_inside_element` (for lack of a better name):

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


class presence_of_element_located_inside_element(object):
    def __init__(self, first_locator, second_locator):
        self.first_locator = first_locator
        self.second_locator = second_locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            first_elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(self.first_locator)
            second_elem = first_elem.find_element_by_css_selector(self.second_locator)
            return second_elem
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return False
```

And then you can use it inside your tests:

```
elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(presence_of_element_located_inside_element('div.myClass1', 'div.myClass2'))
```

This is just for illustrative purposes and only supports string CSS selectors.

It can, of course, be adjusted to take as parameters a `By` type and then you can use different locator strategies for each element.